# React and Jest:Cannot mock Link function from react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, react-router-dom, ts-jest

I am trying to mock the Link object from react-router-dom. I've managed to already mock hooks.

My mock:

```
jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => ({
      useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        pathname: "/another-route",
        search: "",
        hash: "",
        state: null,
        key: "SomeKey",
      }),
      useHistory: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({
        push: (mockString: string) => {},
      }),
      Link: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(<div></div>),
    }));
```

Component rendering in SearchButton.test.tsx file:

```
 const renderSearchButton = () =>
render(
  <ReduxProvider store={store}>
    <SearchButton />
  </ReduxProvider>
);
```

SearchButtonComponent in Searchbutton.tsx file

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname,
    search: mappingPropsToSearchQuery,
  }}
>
  <button
    className={`search-button ${additionalClassName}`}
    onClick={onPressed}
  >
    Szukaj
  </button>
</Link>
```

The error I'm getting:

```
 console.error
  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

  Check the render method of `SearchButton`.
      at SearchButton (/mnt/d/projekty/ReactJs/rezerwuj/rezerwujfrontend/src/interface/components/SearchButton/SearchButton.tsx:24:22)
      at Provider (/mnt/d/projekty/ReactJs/rezerwuj/rezerwujfrontend/node_modules/react-redux/lib/components/Provider.js:21:20)
      at ReduxProvider (/mnt/d/projekty/ReactJs/rezerwuj/rezerwujfrontend/src/stateManagment/ReduxProvider.tsx:17:23)

  26 |   const pathname = "/lista-restauracji";
  27 |   return (
> 28 |     <Link
     |     ^
  29 |       to={{
  30 |         pathname,
  31 |         search: mappingPropsToSearchQuery,
```

I just want to test if the component renders correctly.

Comment: Why you can not mock? Is there any error? How did you use the mock objects? Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I've edited the post already, sorry my bad I didn't have much time, so I haven't put many details.